# Rails 4 Devise 3.1.1 ActionController::UnknownFormat in Devise::RegistrationsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a Rails 4 app using Devise 3.1.1 for user authentication. When I click on /users/sign_up.user link Rails throws following exception:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in Devise::RegistrationsController#new
ActionController::UnknownFormat

Rails.root: /home/rehan/odesk_work/kiefer-waight/ujoin/ujoin-www

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:372:in `retrieve_collector_from_mimes'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:327:in `respond_with'
devise (3.1.1) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:8:in `new'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__890637270__process_action__callbacks'
....
```

I was actually on Devise 3.0.0.rc when started the app, I thought upgrading the devise to 3.1.1 might solve the problem, but it didn't. Couldn't find anything useful on SO/google/devise github project. Any idea how to work around it. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did not want to change default links produced by Devise which appended ".user" at the end of each link. Devise produced following links:

`new_user_registration_path(resource_name) new_user_session_path(resource_name) new_user_password_path(resource_name)`

resource_name, which is user, as parameter to the path in link_to method which tells it to use ".user" as format. So I just removed resource_name from each path. I wonder why Devise does this though!

Comment: I also don't know why they need the `resource` as a parameter. I removed in my case, the parameter and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

@zeeshan's answer works, you can also the functions without the _user infix:

```
new_registration_path(resource_name)

new_session_path(resource_name)

new_password_path(resource_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just resolved this problem also.

**The solution** is to revert all paths to **`Devise` default ones**, meaning to say no `_user` infix.

Note that we ***are not able*** to test in console these code:

```
user = User.all.sample
app.new_registration_path(user)
```

because Devise use its [helper](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb) to transform the url automatically internally so we cannot test from outside.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you click on the `/users/sign_up.user` link, do you literally mean that exact path?  Because the `.user` on the end is telling it to try and respond with a `user` format, akin to `pdf`, `xml`, or `json`.  Remove that and see what happens.