# ActionController::UnknownFormat in Devise::RegistrationsController#new. ".user" appended in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have worked with devise before but i can't understand what i did wrong this time.All the related questions doesn't explain it as well. As soon as i click the SignUp link, i get the error as follows

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in Devise::RegistrationsController#new
```

in line number 207

```
(options.delete(:responder) || self.class.responder).call(self, resources, options)
  else
207: raise ActionController::UnknownFormat
  end
end
```

However, if i change my link from

```
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path(resource_name) %>
```

to

```
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %>
```

the signup page loads just fine. Another thing to note is that when i click the signup link, my url looks like `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up.user` and not like `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up` which should be the case.

I referred [Rails 4 Devise 3.1.1 ActionController::UnknownFormat in Devise::RegistrationsController#new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193222/rails-4-devise-3-1-1-actioncontrollerunknownformat-in-deviseregistrationscon) and found the idea to remove the resource_name and it seems to work. However, i cant understand why. Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a resource into a path method such as `new_user_registration_path`, Rails will try to route to the action for that resource and interpolate it into the route. Since you don't have a route which has the matcher for the resource defined for it, Rails will just append `.<resource.to_param>` onto the end of the URL instead. Obviously this isn't what you want, since sign up doesn't need to take a resource.

The reason you're getting this specific exception is that because devise is attempting to respond to multiple response types (html, json, xml etc), it's parsing .user as the type you wish to receive, hence the unknown format error.

Comment: i dont get it. My new_user_registration_path points to registration/new then why did it not match the path.

Comment: It did, but tried to respond to the `.user` response format which doesn't exist. `resource_name.to_param` is `user`, which is why it got appended to the URL

Comment: ok.. kinda makes sense, but how do i ensure that it doesn't app take resource_name.to_param? I'm sorry for asking such dumb questions but please bear with me, i'm am a newbie in rails

Comment: just don't pass any arguments to the `new_user_registration_path` method in future.

Comment: Yeah, i figured removing the parameter would solve the problem. Now i understand why as well. Thank You :)