# UnknownFormat with Devise and custom controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Rails 5 and Devise.

Because I want custom layouts for login and recover password pages I had to run

```
rails generate devise:controllers
```

I also set my routes to:

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    passwords: 'users/passwords'
  }
```

Login works fine.

Now, when I want my users to change their profile I set a link to

```
edit_user_registration_path
```

Which opens a form where they can set their email and password but when I submit the form I get the error:

> ActionController::UnknownFormat in
>   Devise::RegistrationsController#update

[image]

In the registrations controller everything is commented out because I do not want to use custom code here.

Full trace:

```
responders (2.3.0) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:207:in `respond_with'
devise (4.2.0) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:60:in `update'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:86:in `service'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: The way I understand it is you have created a custom registrations controller inherited from the Devise one but commented everything inside?

Comment: No. rails generate devise:controllers created the controllers for me, with already everything commented out.

Comment: for the same i think you need to specify what you are responding to specify in registrations controller  below code : respond_to :html, :json

Comment: could you give us the full stack trace you get in the logs with the detailed error?

Comment: @TusharPal since he hasn't overriden Devise registrations controller, there's no point in that

Comment: Do you really have to create new controllers for custom login and reset ui page? I thought you can just edit `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` and `app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb`?

Comment: @amree that is correct, but I want to use a different layout (layout folder) because those pages are outside the actual app (no navbar etc.)

Comment: @almo I can't understand you what need it for layout

Comment: Open your edit registration page and checkout the form `action` (use inspect element). It shouldn't be ending with anything else. The correct one is supposed to be like `/users`. You may have something like `/users.user`. Can you check that one first?

Comment: This could solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19194805/113573